# Proving by induction that if $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ is a finite set of open intervals with covers $[a,b]$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\space I_k| = b-a$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to give an inductive proof that if $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ is a finite set of open intervals with covers $[a,b]$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\space I_k| = b-a$.

My proof is as follows:

Suppose $n=1$.Then, $\{I_1\}$ is a finite set of open intervals which covers $[a,b]$. If $\{I_1\}$ covers $[a,b]$, then the length of $|I_1| \geq b-a$. Now, for $n=2$,

$I_1 \cup I_2$ covers $[a,b]$, then $|I_1|+|I_2| \geq b-a$. Assuming $n$ holds, assume that 
$\{I_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ covers $[a,b]$ and that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\space I_k| \geq b-a$.

Because $|I_{k+1}| \geq 0$, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} |\space I_k| = |I_1| 
+...+ |I_{n+1}| \geq |I_1| +...+ |I_{n}|\geq b-a$.

Hence, the induction step holds and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |\space I_k| = b-a$.

I smell something fishy in my proof above, but don't know where to proceed. Would anyone be kind enough to lead me along? Thanks!

Comment: In every place where you say *"with covers $[a,b]$"* do you mean *"which covers $[a,b]$"*?

Comment: If $I_1\dots I_{n+1}$ cover $[a,b]$, there is no reason to assume that $I_1\dots I_n$ also cover $[a,b]$. The induction step is wrong. Besides that you 'prove' only $\ge |b-a|$ not $=|b-a|$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 
$$\inf\{ \sum_{n=1}^k |I_n| : [a,b]\subset \cup_{n=1}^k I_n\} = b-a ?$$
The statement you are trying to proof is false, take $a=b$, any open interval that covers $[a,a]$ will always have positive length.

Answer (score 0):

The fishy part is that it's not true? In my definition a cover can have overlaps and can extend beyond the covered set, either of which means that the theorem should be an inequality and not equality.